# Multiclass Classification Output in MLPClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Using [MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier) to solve a Multiclass problem (classes represented as integer values from 0 to 11). Does it internally convert the classes to one-hot-encode format and creates a network with 12 outputs? Or it creates a network with a single output node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MLPClassifier` inherits from `BaseMultilayerPerceptron`, which uses `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer`.

This is what [`LabelBinarizer`'s docu](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) says:

> Binarize labels in a one-vs-all fashion.

Based on this, `MLPClassifier` does internally convert the classes to a one-hot encoded format for the training process, and thus, for a multiclass problem, it creates a neural network with an output layer consisting of as many nodes as there are classes—in this case, 12 nodes for classes 0 to 11. Each output node corresponds to the presence of a class. However, it's important to note that `MLPClassifier` uses these nodes in conjunction with a softmax activation function to output a probability distribution for the multi-class labels, rather than training separate binary classifiers for each class.